# NullPointerException Java android studio setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance())

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I'm still new with coding but I have a project with android studio right now. What I wanted to do was to add hyperlinks in a page. I've followed the steps and tutorials to do this very carefully but I can't seem to find the problem. In my Logcat it says

```
 PID: 17644 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setMovementMethod(android.text.method.MovementMethod)' on a null object reference
```

but I don't understand how it was caused. I have read some similar problems stating the findByViewId might be wrong but I don't think that is the case for my problem but I would love to be wrong. Here is my code. Any help is much appreciated.

```
  public class LearnFragment extends Fragment {

    private Button search;
    private TextView faq_link_1, faq_link_2, faq_link_3, faq_link_4, faq_link_5;
    EditText editSearch;

    public LearnFragment() {
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View viewRoot = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_account, container, false);

        faq_link_1 = (TextView) viewRoot.findViewById(R.id.faq1);
        faq_link_2 = (TextView) viewRoot.findViewById(R.id.faq2);
        faq_link_3 = (TextView) viewRoot.findViewById(R.id.faq3);
        faq_link_4 = (TextView) viewRoot.findViewById(R.id.faq4);
        faq_link_5 = (TextView) viewRoot.findViewById(R.id.faq5);

        
        faq_link_1.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        faq_link_2.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        faq_link_3.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        faq_link_4.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

and this is the xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".boundary.LearnFragment">

    

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/search_bar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:hint="Search..."
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/b_search"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.158"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b_search"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Search"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/search_bar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/faq1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
        android:text="@string/link_period_pain"
        android:textSize="23sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:linksClickable="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/faq2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="27dp"
        android:text="@string/menstrual_cramp_link"
        android:textSize="23sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/faq3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/faq1"
        android:linksClickable="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/faq3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:text="@string/late_period_link"
        android:textSize="23sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/faq4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/faq2"
        android:linksClickable="true"   />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/faq4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:text="@string/cervical_screening_link"
        android:textSize="23sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/faq5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/faq3"
        android:linksClickable="true"   />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/faq5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
        android:text="@string/pap_smear_link"
        android:textSize="23sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/faq4"
        android:linksClickable="true"   />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:text="Not looking what you're looking for? Use the search bar to find out more!"
        android:textSize="23sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/search_bar" />




</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: 1. You sure fragment_account is the xml posted? 2. Try adding `.setText("?")` to any textview before `.setMovementMethod()` to see if the view initialization is correct. 3. Maybe `LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()` is null?

Comment: I agree with @javdromero, check if `LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()` isn't null.

Comment: Thanks so much for the comments! But I have found the problem!